# From iPhone 4 to iPhone 5 screen size compatibility issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone-5, screen-size

I am working on the existing application. My task is to optimize screen to make compatible to screen for iphone 5. The original image as it could be seen in the first image (width and height 320*460). I have scale image to 320*548 and then used freeform in the inspector section, however, still bottom part of the screen is shown black. Any idea?

This initial image (320*460) screen shot got from iPhone 5 [image]

This image (320*548) screen shot got from iPhone 5 !![image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcM4k.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to optimize your application for iphone-5 also you need to include a Launch Image of dimension `640*1136` and name the image as

> Default-568@2x.png

. UIApplication automatically detect the Device screen size if it found the `Default-568@2x.png` it launches the App accordingly . After adding the image , clean your Derived Data and also clean the project using `cmd+shift+k` . After that relaunch the App .

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 3):

If you are creating the app for iPhone 4 & iPhone 5 THE BEST WAY TO USE `autolayouts`, but the app will run `iOS 6.0 or later` but the screen resolution problem will be resolved. or as an alternative you can use auto resizing. This resolution problem occurs because the screen of iPhone 5 is `640*1136`.
Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 2):

You also need to provide a `Default-586h@2x.png` file with your application. Only then, iOS "enables" the full resolution for your app.